# How To Pass Props To Function Component use react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to pass props into a function from the route, my code currently looks like this

**Route**

```
 <Route path="/person" render={(params) => <ProductDetails {...params} />} />
```

**Code**

```
function ProductDetails(props) {  
  return (  
    <div className="section has-text-centered mt-4">  
      console.log(props)  
      <h1>Hello</h1>  
    </div>  
  );  
};  
export default ProductDetails;
```

What am I missing here, please help.

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom` v6 you pass props to the routed component directly since they are passed as a `ReactElement` (*a.k.a. JSX*).

Example:

```
<Route path="person" element={<ProductDetails /* pass props here */ />} />
```

Based on your example snippet though, it sounds like your question it more specifically about passing the "route props" to a component. In RRDv6 there are no longer any route props, i.e. no `history`, `location`, and `match` props. Use the React hooks to access these: `useNavigate` for navigation, `useLocation` for `location`, and `useMatch` for `match` and `useParams` specifically for the route params.

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductDetails(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const match = useMatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);

  return (  
    <div className="section has-text-centered mt-4"> 
      <h1>Hello</h1>  
    </div>  
  );  
};  
export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: I don't have the value of the props to pass the props in element tag you need to have a neme of prpps and *Value*, I want to get the propsParamas

Comment: @GF7ER-فيلو I thought my answer was clear about there no longer being any route props to pass along, and how to access the same values in `react-router-dom` v6. What other props are you trying to pass along? Pass these as you would normally to the component rendered by the route.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function with props in **React Router DOM V6** in this way:

```
<Route path="/person" element={<ProductDetails render={(params) => ({ ...params })} />} />
```

And you can pass more props as names outside of render function.

Example:

```
<Route path="/person" element={<ProductDetails render={(params) => ({ ...params })} user={user} />} />
```